# Determining what classes are defined in a PHP class file

Tags: php, class

Given that each PHP file in our project contains a single class definition, how can I determine what class or classes are defined within the file?

I know I could just regex the file for `class` statements, but I'd prefer to do something that's more efficient.

Comment: What's the purpose of getting the class name of each file?  The best solution should be tailored to fit your problem space.  As it stands I feel as though there's probably a better solution depending on what you're looking to do.

Comment: It's been a while, but still: you could call `get_declared_classes`, save it, include the class file, and call `get_declared_classes` again. The difference is in that file. Simple.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I needed something like this for a project I am working on, and here are the functions I wrote:

```
function file_get_php_classes($filepath) {
  $php_code = file_get_contents($filepath);
  $classes = get_php_classes($php_code);
  return $classes;
}

function get_php_classes($php_code) {
  $classes = array();
  $tokens = token_get_all($php_code);
  $count = count($tokens);
  for ($i = 2; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if (   $tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS
        && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE
        && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING) {

        $class_name = $tokens[$i][1];
        $classes[] = $class_name;
    }
  }
  return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Not all tokens are arrays so this can give some warnings.

Comment: @hakre: It wouldn't because if `$tokens[$i]` is a string, the syntax `$tokens[i][0]` is still allowed.

Comment: Right, but I suggest to use `===` for comparisons in that case.

Comment: A version with namespaces is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761554/php-get-all-class-names-inside-a-particular-namespace/27440555#27440555

Comment: Just to be thorough, I wanted to verify that the syntax specified here matches the language specification. It does! https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/14-classes.md#class-declarations

Answer (score 16):

If you just want to check a file without loading it use [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$php_file = file_get_contents('c2.php');
$tokens = token_get_all($php_file);
$class_token = false;
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
  if (is_array($token)) {
    if ($token[0] == T_CLASS) {
       $class_token = true;
    } else if ($class_token && $token[0] == T_STRING) {
       echo "Found class: $token[1]\n";
       $class_token = false;
    }
  }       
}
?>
```

Basically, this is a simple finite state machine. In PHP the sequence of [tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) will be:

- `T_CLASS`: 'class' keyword;
- `T_WHITESPACE`: space(s) after 'class';
- `T_STRING`: name of class.

So this code will handle any weird spacing or newlines you get just fine because it's using the same parser PHP uses to execute the file. If `token_get_all()` can't parse it, neither can PHP.

By the way, you use [`token_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-name.php) to turn a token number into it's constant name.

Here is my c2.php:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
  public __construct() {
  }
}

class MyOtherClass {
  public __construct() {
  }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Found class: MyClass
Found class: MyOtherClass
```

Comment: Please note that something like `User::class` is valid syntax for retrieving the FQCN string (like "App\Model\User") since PHP 5.5. So you either need to explicitly check for the T_WHITESPACE (and nothing else) in between, or you could check for an absence of T_COLON before T_CLASS.

Answer (score 6):

Or you could easily use AnnotationsParser from [Nette\Reflection](https://github.com/nette/reflection) (installable using composer):

```
use Nette\Reflection\AnnotationsParser;
$classes = AnnotationsParser::parsePhp(file_get_contents($fileName));
var_dump($classes);
```

Output will be then something like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["Your\Class\Name"] =>
  array(...) {
      // property => comment
  },
  ["Your\Class\Second"] =>
  array(...) {
      // property => comment
  },
}
```

The [parsePhp() method](https://github.com/nette/reflection/blob/master/src/Reflection/AnnotationsParser.php#L274) basically does something similar as examples in other answers, but you don't have to declare nor test the parsing yourselves.

Answer (score 5):

I needed parse classes from file with namespaces, so I modified code. If somebody need too, here is it:

```
public function getPhpClasses($phpcode) {
    $classes = array();

    $namespace = 0;  
    $tokens = token_get_all($phpcode); 
    $count = count($tokens); 
    $dlm = false;
    for ($i = 2; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        if ((isset($tokens[$i - 2][1]) && ($tokens[$i - 2][1] == "phpnamespace" || $tokens[$i - 2][1] == "namespace")) || 
            ($dlm && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_NS_SEPARATOR && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING)) { 
            if (!$dlm) $namespace = 0; 
            if (isset($tokens[$i][1])) {
                $namespace = $namespace ? $namespace . "\\" . $tokens[$i][1] : $tokens[$i][1];
                $dlm = true; 
            }   
        }       
        elseif ($dlm && ($tokens[$i][0] != T_NS_SEPARATOR) && ($tokens[$i][0] != T_STRING)) {
            $dlm = false; 
        } 
        if (($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS || (isset($tokens[$i - 2][1]) && $tokens[$i - 2][1] == "phpclass")) 
                && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING) {
            $class_name = $tokens[$i][1]; 
            if (!isset($classes[$namespace])) $classes[$namespace] = array();
            $classes[$namespace][] = $class_name;
        }
    } 
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't make your snippet work with files with multiple namespaces

Answer (score 4):

My snippet too. Can parse files with multiple classes, interfaces, arrays and namespaces.
Returns an array with classes+types (class, interface, abstract) divided by namespaces.

```
<?php    
    /**
     * 
     * Looks what classes and namespaces are defined in that file and returns the first found
     * @param String $file Path to file
     * @return Returns NULL if none is found or an array with namespaces and classes found in file
     */
    function classes_in_file($file)
    {

        $classes = $nsPos = $final = array();
        $foundNS = FALSE;
        $ii = 0;

        if (!file_exists($file)) return NULL;

        $er = error_reporting();
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

        $php_code = file_get_contents($file);
        $tokens = token_get_all($php_code);
        $count = count($tokens);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
        {
            if(!$foundNS && $tokens[$i][0] == T_NAMESPACE)
            {
                $nsPos[$ii]['start'] = $i;
                $foundNS = TRUE;
            }
            elseif( $foundNS && ($tokens[$i] == ';' || $tokens[$i] == '{') )
            {
                $nsPos[$ii]['end']= $i;
                $ii++;
                $foundNS = FALSE;
            }
            elseif ($i-2 >= 0 && $tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING) 
            {
                if($i-4 >=0 && $tokens[$i - 4][0] == T_ABSTRACT)
                {
                    $classes[$ii][] = array('name' => $tokens[$i][1], 'type' => 'ABSTRACT CLASS');
                }
                else
                {
                    $classes[$ii][] = array('name' => $tokens[$i][1], 'type' => 'CLASS');
                }
            }
            elseif ($i-2 >= 0 && $tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_INTERFACE && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING)
            {
                $classes[$ii][] = array('name' => $tokens[$i][1], 'type' => 'INTERFACE');
            }
        }
        error_reporting($er);
        if (empty($classes)) return NULL;

        if(!empty($nsPos))
        {
            foreach($nsPos as $k => $p)
            {
                $ns = '';
                for($i = $p['start'] + 1; $i < $p['end']; $i++)
                    $ns .= $tokens[$i][1];

                $ns = trim($ns);
                $final[$k] = array('namespace' => $ns, 'classes' => $classes[$k+1]);
            }
            $classes = $final;
        }
        return $classes;
    }
```

Outputs something like this...

```
array
  'namespace' => string 'test\foo' (length=8)
  'classes' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'name' => string 'bar' (length=3)
          'type' => string 'CLASS' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array
          'name' => string 'baz' (length=3)
          'type' => string 'INTERFACE' (length=9)
array
  'namespace' => string 'this\is\a\really\big\namespace\for\testing\dont\you\think' (length=57)
  'classes' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'name' => string 'yes_it_is' (length=9)
          'type' => string 'CLASS' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array
          'name' => string 'damn_too_big' (length=12)
          'type' => string 'ABSTRACT CLASS' (length=14)
      2 => 
        array
          'name' => string 'fogo' (length=6)
          'type' => string 'INTERFACE' (length=9)
```

Might help someone!

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP's function **get_declared_classes()**. This returns an array of classes defined in the current script.

Comment: So, I'd need to compare this with the list of classes from before the include... or can you think of something more efficient?

Comment: If you're loading the files via an include, that's the most efficient method I can think of.

Comment: If you want to find out what classes are in a file, this won't do it. You can't compare get_declared_classes() before and after an include because the file may already be included/autoloaded/required.

Comment: Correct. This is assuming that it hasn't already been included.

Comment: include_once will return true if the file has already been included, so you could check if the file has been included already before using get_declared_classes

Comment: Yes but that doesn't help you determine what the classes are if it already has been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I've extended Venkat D's answer a bit to include returning the methods, and to search through a directory. (This specific example is built for CodeIgniter, which will return all the methods in the ./system/application/controller files - in other words, every public url that you can call through the system.)

```
function file_get_php_classes($filepath,$onlypublic=true) {
    $php_code = file_get_contents($filepath);
    $classes = get_php_classes($php_code,$onlypublic);
    return $classes;
}

function get_php_classes($php_code,$onlypublic) {
    $classes = array();
    $methods=array();
    $tokens = token_get_all($php_code);
    $count = count($tokens);
    for ($i = 2; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS
        && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE
        && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING) {
            $class_name = $tokens[$i][1];
            $methods[$class_name] = array();
        }
        if ($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_FUNCTION
        && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE
        && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING) {
            if ($onlypublic) {
                if ( !in_array($tokens[$i-4][0],array(T_PROTECTED, T_PRIVATE))) {
                    $method_name = $tokens[$i][1];
                    $methods[$class_name][] = $method_name;
                }
            } else {
                $method_name = $tokens[$i][1];
                $methods[$class_name][] = $method_name;
            }
        }
    }
    return $methods;
}

function mapSystemClasses($controllerdir="./system/application/controllers/",$onlypublic=true) {
    $result=array();
    $dh=opendir($controllerdir);
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if (substr($file,0,1)!=".") {
            if (filetype($controllerdir.$file)=="file") {
                $classes=file_get_php_classes($controllerdir.$file,$onlypublic);
                foreach($classes as $class=>$method) {
                    $result[]=array("file"=>$controllerdir.$file,"class"=>$class,"method"=>$method);

                }
            } else {
                $result=array_merge($result,mapSystemClasses($controllerdir.$file."/",$onlypublic));
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (2022) you can use the Composer package [roave/better-reflection](https://packagist.org/packages/roave/better-reflection).

To get all classes defined in a file you can use this code with version 5 of the package:

```php
use Roave\BetterReflection\BetterReflection;
use Roave\BetterReflection\Reflector\DefaultReflector;
use Roave\BetterReflection\SourceLocator\Type\SingleFileSourceLocator;

$astLocator = (new BetterReflection())->astLocator();
$reflector = new DefaultReflector(new SingleFileSourceLocator('path/to/file.php', $astLocator));
$classes = $reflector->reflectAllClasses();

$classNames = [];
foreach ($classes as $class) {
    $classNames[] = $class->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore abstract classes like this (note the T_ABSTRACT token):

```
function get_php_classes($php_code)
{
    $classes = array();
    $tokens = token_get_all($php_code);
    $count = count($tokens);
    for ($i = 2; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        if ($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING && !($tokens[$i - 3] && $i - 4 >= 0 && $tokens[$i - 4][0] == T_ABSTRACT))
        {
            $class_name = $tokens[$i][1];
            $classes[] = $class_name;
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: This will raise Illegal Offset since for count starts at 2 and negative numbers are not legal array keys. (2-4 = -2)... You can correct this if you add the condition $i-4>=0 before testing for T_ABSTRACT.