# php create instance of loaded model in controller

Tags: php, oop

**Question:**

```
// TODO: add $name to $models array in Controller class
```

How to add `$name` from function `model()` in `Load` class to `$models` array in `Controller` class ?

*Note: I have `Load` and `Controller` classes in separated files.*

**PHP:**

```
<?php

class Controller {

    public $models = array();
    public $load;

    //TODO: for each model create instance
    // public $name;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load = new Load();

        // TODO: for each model create instance
        // $this->name = new Name();
    }

}

class Load {

    public function model($name) {
        require(APP_DIR . 'models/' . strtolower($name) . '.php');
        $model = new $name;
        // TODO: add $name to $models array in Controller class
        return $model;
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

My Goal:
If I load model in Controller as this: `$this->load->model('model_name');` then I want to have instance of that loaded model as `$this->model_name->method();`

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: If I load model in controller I want to create instance of model in Controller so I can then use model as `$this->model_name->method();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not using any local properties in the Load class, you could make the model method static:

```
public static function model($name) {
    require(APP_DIR . 'models/' . strtolower($name) . '.php');
    $model = new $name;
    // TODO: add $name to $models array in Controller class
    return $model;
}
```

You can then call that method from your Controller class as follows:

```
$model = Load::model($name);
```

**Update**:

You commented:

> If I load model somewhere I want to create instance in Controller so I can then use model as $this->model_name->method();

You can use the magic method `__get` ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)) to access your model in such a way.

Add the following method to your Controller class:

```
public function __get($model) {
    return Load::model($model);
}
```

After adding this function `$this->model_name->somemethod()` will work in your Controller.

Obviously this needs some fine tuning, but it will do what you want.

Comment: If I load model in Controller as this: `$this->load->model('model_name');` then I want to have instance of that loaded model as `$this->model_name->method();`

Comment: See updated answers. Magic method __get will do this for you. Just find tune it to your wishes. You could ofcourse do the loads earlier and store them in in a array property, and then adjust the __get method to return models from that array only if they exist.

Comment: Is this good example what I am trying to achieve ? [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3652341/1183662](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3652341/1183662)

Comment: You can use `class_exists` before doing the require yes. Otherwise you would require it even if it was already loaded.