# How to access keys and first string value while traversing a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

Desired result: "My preferred salty food is the snack Rufles".
I would like to echo the array "snack" inside the array "salty food" as a string:

```
$food = array(
    "salty food" => array(
        "snack" => array(
            0 => "Rufles",
            1 => "Generic"
        )
    )
);

echo "My prefered ";

foreach($food as $key => $value)     //salty food
    echo $key;

echo " is the ";

//--MY DOUBT IS HERE. DESIRED ECHO: "snack" (FROM THE DEEP ARRAY):
foreach($food as $key => $value)
    echo $key["snack"];

print_r($food["salty food"]["snack"][0]);     //Rufles
```

Comment: and what is the code output?

Comment: What should it print if the arrays have more than one element?

Comment: Why are you using loops to print `salty food` and `snack`, but then hard-coding them in the `print_r()` at the end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP How to access all elements of multidimensional array if no indexes are known?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824788/php-how-to-access-all-elements-of-multidimensional-array-if-no-indexes-are-known)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be ok

```
<?php 

    $food = array(
        "salty food" => array(
            "snack" => array(
                0 => "Rufles",
                1 => "Generic"
                )
            )
    );

    echo "My prefered ";

    foreach($food as $key1 => $value){
        echo $key1;    
        echo " is the ";        
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value){
            echo $key2." ";
        }        
    }    
    print_r($food["salty food"]["snack"][0]);


?>
```

Comment: This will just print `My preferred salty food is the salty food`. You're looping over the same array both times.

Comment: It produces: "My prefered salty food is the salty foodRufles"

Comment: My bad! Now is ok

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops:

```
echo "My preferred ";
foreach ($food as $type1 => $value1) {
    echo $type1;
    echo " is the ";
    foreach ($value1 as $type2 => $value2) {
        echo "$type2 $value2[0]";
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/MZ8LDs)