# Get class name from file

Tags: php, reflection

I have a php file which contains only one class. how can I know what class is there by knowing the filename? I know I can do something with regexp matching but is there a standard php way? (the file is already included in the page that is trying to figure out the class name).

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928928/determining-what-classes-are-defined-in-a-php-class-file

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are multiple possible solutions to this problem, each with their advantages and disadvantages. Here they are, it's up to know to decide which one you want.

### Tokenizer

This method uses the tokenizer and reads parts of the file until it finds a class definition.

**Advantages**

- Do not have to parse the file entirely
- Fast (reads the beginning of the file only)
- Little to no chance of false positives

**Disadvantages**

- Longest solution

**Code**

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
$class = $buffer = '';
$i = 0;
while (!$class) {
    if (feof($fp)) break;

    $buffer .= fread($fp, 512);
    $tokens = token_get_all($buffer);

    if (strpos($buffer, '{') === false) continue;

    for (;$i<count($tokens);$i++) {
        if ($tokens[$i][0] === T_CLASS) {
            for ($j=$i+1;$j<count($tokens);$j++) {
                if ($tokens[$j] === '{') {
                    $class = $tokens[$i+2][1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Regular expressions

Use regular expressions to parse the beginning of the file, until a class definition is found.

**Advantages**

- Do not have to parse the file entirely
- Fast (reads the beginning of the file only)

**Disadvantages**

- High chances of false positives (e.g.: `echo "class Foo {";`)

**Code**

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
$class = $buffer = '';
$i = 0;
while (!$class) {
    if (feof($fp)) break;

    $buffer .= fread($fp, 512);
    if (preg_match('/class\s+(\w+)(.*)?\{/', $buffer, $matches)) {
        $class = $matches[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

*Note: The regex can probably be improved, but no regex alone can do this perfectly.*

### Get list of declared classes

This method uses `get_declared_classes()` and look for the first class defined after an include.

**Advantages**

- Shortest solution
- No chance of false positive

**Disadvantages**

- Have to load the entire file
- Have to load the entire list of classes in memory *twice*
- Have to load the class definition in memory

**Code**

```
$classes = get_declared_classes();
include 'test2.php';
$diff = array_diff(get_declared_classes(), $classes);
$class = reset($diff);
```

*Note: You cannot simply do `end()` as others suggested. If the class includes another class, you will get a wrong result.*

---

This is the **Tokenizer** solution, modified to include a *$namespace* variable containing the class namespace, if applicable:

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
$class = $namespace = $buffer = '';
$i = 0;
while (!$class) {
    if (feof($fp)) break;

    $buffer .= fread($fp, 512);
    $tokens = token_get_all($buffer);

    if (strpos($buffer, '{') === false) continue;

    for (;$i<count($tokens);$i++) {
        if ($tokens[$i][0] === T_NAMESPACE) {
            for ($j=$i+1;$j<count($tokens); $j++) {
                if ($tokens[$j][0] === T_STRING) {
                     $namespace .= '\\'.$tokens[$j][1];
                } else if ($tokens[$j] === '{' || $tokens[$j] === ';') {
                     break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($tokens[$i][0] === T_CLASS) {
            for ($j=$i+1;$j<count($tokens);$j++) {
                if ($tokens[$j] === '{') {
                    $class = $tokens[$i+2][1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Say you have this class:

```
namespace foo\bar {
    class hello { }
}
```

...or the alternative syntax:

```
namespace foo\bar;
class hello { }
```

You should have the following result:

```
var_dump($namespace); // \foo\bar
var_dump($class);     // hello
```

You could also use the above to detect the namespace a file declares, regardless of it containing a class or not.

Comment: Nice answer. I'll go for the tokenizer, it seems false positives are impossible there.

Comment: How would this work to include namespaces of the class as well? As in, returning the FULL class name prefixed with namespaces?

Comment: Weird that `T_NAMESPACE` is just a `namespace` word and actual namespace value is of type `T_STRING`!

Comment: There is a problem when using Tokenizer solution and `fread($fp, 512)` returns code with "unfinished" comment, passing this string to `token_get_all` will result in PHP Warning "Unterminated comment starting line x..." this renders Tokenizer solution useless if you're using comments in code.

Comment: @tadasZ : the warning can be suppressed by putting an @ sign in front of token_get_all.

Comment: @netcoder, `if (strpos($buffer, '{') === false) continue;` will lead to a false positive if a class has a docblock with inline phpdoc comments (`/** bla bla {@see SomeClass} {@link http://example.com}`). So you need to filter them (T_DOC_COMMENT) out before check.

Comment: @netcoder For PHP 5.5+ code tokenizer solution gives false positive on use [`::class`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) statement because it have `T_CLASS` token code. Example: `print_r(token_get_all('<?php $a=\stdClass::class;'));`

Comment: I made my own function largely based on this answer with the new tokens provided in PHP 8 (we now have T_NAME_QUALIFIED for the namespace). It relies less on string matching and I've found it quite robust from some quick testing. Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/cwhite92/f0aaf008e1679b27768fbb8c884df6f7

Answer (score 8):

You can make PHP do the work by just including the file and get the last declared class:

```
$file = 'class.php'; # contains class Foo

include($file);
$classes = get_declared_classes();
$class = end($classes);
echo $class; # Foo
```

If you need to isolate that, wrap it into a commandline script and execute it via `shell_exec`:

```
$file = 'class.php'; # contains class Foo

$class = shell_exec("php -r \"include('$file'); echo end(get_declared_classes());\"");    
echo $class; # Foo
```

If you dislike commandline scripts, you can do it like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928928/determining-what-classes-are-defined-in-a-php-class-file), however that code does not reflect namespaces.

Comment: I can't, the file is included automatically before my file runs and its not the last that is included.

Comment: @Dani: I added an example how to do that via commandline, however, you might run into problems when a class depends on another one etc. - however it should show you the idea.

Comment: Note that this approach require working autoloader for all parent classes and implemented interfaces. It also executes PHP code outside the class declaration (if such code exists), which may be undesired.

Answer (score 6):

I modified `Nette\Reflection\AnnotationsParser` that so it returns an array of namespace+classname that are defined in the file

```
$parser = new PhpParser();
$parser->extractPhpClasses('src/Path/To/File.php');


class PhpParser
{
    public function extractPhpClasses(string $path)
    {
        $code = file_get_contents($path);
        $tokens = @token_get_all($code);
        $namespace = $class = $classLevel = $level = NULL;
        $classes = [];
        while (list(, $token) = each($tokens)) {
            switch (is_array($token) ? $token[0] : $token) {
                case T_NAMESPACE:
                    $namespace = ltrim($this->fetch($tokens, [T_STRING, T_NS_SEPARATOR]) . '\\', '\\');
                    break;
                case T_CLASS:
                case T_INTERFACE:
                    if ($name = $this->fetch($tokens, T_STRING)) {
                        $classes[] = $namespace . $name;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $classes;
    }

    private function fetch(&$tokens, $take)
    {
        $res = NULL;
        while ($token = current($tokens)) {
            list($token, $s) = is_array($token) ? $token : [$token, $token];
            if (in_array($token, (array) $take, TRUE)) {
                $res .= $s;
            } elseif (!in_array($token, [T_DOC_COMMENT, T_WHITESPACE, T_COMMENT], TRUE)) {
                break;
            }
            next($tokens);
        }
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$st = get_declared_classes();
include "classes.php"; //one or more classes in file, contains class class1, class2, etc...

$res = array_values(array_diff_key(get_declared_classes(),$st));
print_r($res); # Array ([0] => class1 [1] => class2 [2] ...)
```

Comment: This is a very clever answer!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to some people from Stackoverflow and Github, I was able to write this amazing fully working solution:

```
/**
 * get the full name (name \ namespace) of a class from its file path
 * result example: (string) "I\Am\The\Namespace\Of\This\Class"
 *
 * @param $filePathName
 *
 * @return  string
 */
public function getClassFullNameFromFile($filePathName)
{
    return $this->getClassNamespaceFromFile($filePathName) . '\\' . $this->getClassNameFromFile($filePathName);
}


/**
 * build and return an object of a class from its file path
 *
 * @param $filePathName
 *
 * @return  mixed
 */
public function getClassObjectFromFile($filePathName)
{
    $classString = $this->getClassFullNameFromFile($filePathName);

    $object = new $classString;

    return $object;
}





/**
 * get the class namespace form file path using token
 *
 * @param $filePathName
 *
 * @return  null|string
 */
protected function getClassNamespaceFromFile($filePathName)
{
    $src = file_get_contents($filePathName);

    $tokens = token_get_all($src);
    $count = count($tokens);
    $i = 0;
    $namespace = '';
    $namespace_ok = false;
    while ($i < $count) {
        $token = $tokens[$i];
        if (is_array($token) && $token[0] === T_NAMESPACE) {
            // Found namespace declaration
            while (++$i < $count) {
                if ($tokens[$i] === ';') {
                    $namespace_ok = true;
                    $namespace = trim($namespace);
                    break;
                }
                $namespace .= is_array($tokens[$i]) ? $tokens[$i][1] : $tokens[$i];
            }
            break;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if (!$namespace_ok) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return $namespace;
    }
}

/**
 * get the class name form file path using token
 *
 * @param $filePathName
 *
 * @return  mixed
 */
protected function getClassNameFromFile($filePathName)
{
    $php_code = file_get_contents($filePathName);

    $classes = array();
    $tokens = token_get_all($php_code);
    $count = count($tokens);
    for ($i = 2; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS
            && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE
            && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING
        ) {

            $class_name = $tokens[$i][1];
            $classes[] = $class_name;
        }
    }

    return $classes[0];
}
```

Comment: Do you have this solution published on github? I also found this article http://jarretbyrne.com/2015/06/197/ , is it your?

Comment: Nop it's not published on Github but it's part of one of my open source projects on Github "Hello API" https://github.com/Mahmoudz/Hello-API/blob/master/app/Port/Butler/Portals/PortButler.php, and no that article is not mine.

Comment: This solution will not work if you have defined multiple namespaces on a single file

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two ways:

- **complex solution**: open the file and through regex extract the class-name (like `/class ([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)/`)
- **simply solution**: name all your php files with the class-name contained (eg: the class `TestFoo` in the file `TestFoo.php` or `TestFoo.class.php`)

Comment: the regex is provided directly from php.net documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 2):

You could get all declared classes before you include the file using [`get_declared_classes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php). Do the same thing after you have included it and compare the two with something like [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and you have your newly added class.

Comment: I can't... my file gets executed only after the file was included and I can't change it.

Comment: I believe the dot after first sentence need to be comma. If it is a dot, your first sentence becomes invalid since it is considered answer to question.

Answer (score 2):

This sample returns all classes. If you're looking for a class which is derived of a specific one, use is_subclass_of

```
$php_code = file_get_contents ( $file );
    $classes = array ();
    $namespace="";
    $tokens = token_get_all ( $php_code );
    $count = count ( $tokens );

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++)
    {
        if ($tokens[$i][0]===T_NAMESPACE)
        {
            for ($j=$i+1;$j<$count;++$j)
            {
                if ($tokens[$j][0]===T_STRING)
                    $namespace.="\\".$tokens[$j][1];
                elseif ($tokens[$j]==='{' or $tokens[$j]===';')
                    break;
            }
        }
        if ($tokens[$i][0]===T_CLASS)
        {
            for ($j=$i+1;$j<$count;++$j)
                if ($tokens[$j]==='{')
                {
                    $classes[]=$namespace."\\".$tokens[$i+2][1];
                }
        }
    }
    return $classes;
```

Comment: good hint on `is_subclass_of` which will reduce the noise on what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

I spent lots of productive time looking for a way around this.
From @netcoder's solution its obvious there are lots of cons in all the solutions so far.

So I decided to do this instead.
Since most PHP classes has class name same as filename, we could get the class name from the filename. Depending on your project you could also  have a naming convention.
NB: This assume class does not have namespace

```
<?php
    $path = '/path/to/a/class/file.php';

    include $path;

    /*get filename without extension which is the classname*/
    $classname = pathinfo(basename($path), PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    /* you can do all this*/
    $classObj = new $classname();

    /*dough the file name is classname you can still*/
    get_class($classObj); //still return classname
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me add a PHP 8 compatible solution as well. This will scan a file accordingly and return all FQCN's:

```php
$file      = 'whatever.php';
$classes   = [];
$namespace = '';
$tokens    = PhpToken::tokenize(file_get_contents($file));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($tokens); $i++) {
    if ($tokens[$i]->getTokenName() === 'T_NAMESPACE') {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($tokens); $j++) {
            if ($tokens[$j]->getTokenName() === 'T_NAME_QUALIFIED') {
                $namespace = $tokens[$j]->text;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($tokens[$i]->getTokenName() === 'T_CLASS') {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($tokens); $j++) {
            if ($tokens[$j]->getTokenName() === 'T_WHITESPACE') {
                continue;
            }

            if ($tokens[$j]->getTokenName() === 'T_STRING') {
                $classes[] = $namespace . '\\' . $tokens[$j]->text;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Contains all FQCNs found in a file.
$classes;
```

Comment: **This** should be the accepted answer at 2024!

**Example gist:** https://gist.github.com/rboonzaijer/46af1e83ca8a018393ec8aab01a9c32e 

- It gives the complete namespace + classname (so you can instantiate the class directly with `$model = new $className();`)

- It uses the new PhpToken class (which is more memory efficient then the older token_get_all() according to 
 https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.phptoken.php )

- It returns multiple classnames in a single file

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use the autoload function.

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include "special_directory/" .$class_name . '.php';
}
```

And you can echo $class_name. But that requires a directory with a single file.

But it is standard practice to have one class in each file in PHP. So Main.class.php will contain Main class. You may able to use that standard if you are the one coding.

Comment: this is the inverse process: from the class name you generate a filepath, Dani instead need know the class name from the file.

Comment: It is not inverse, since you do not call it directly with a class name, but this will only work when the filename and class name are the same (now that I read on PHP's website) for example, MyClass.php contains MyClass class. So I would think, the naming convention strategy is the most efficient and fastest strategy in this case.

Comment: I agree with you on the naming convention, but personally I think the __autoload is useless here, for use that should be done.