# How to get all methods of all classes within a specific folder

Tags: php

I've been reading through the following somewhat similar questions:

- [Determining what classes are defined in a PHP class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928928/determining-what-classes-are-defined-in-a-php-class-file)
- [Get class name from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153000/get-class-name-from-file)

But those are specific to class names only. I'm wondering if there is an efficient way (using [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) or otherwise) to retrieve all the methods contained in all the classes within a specific folder?

My initial thoughts are that I could traverse the directory using the [`FilesystemIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php), then use the [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) to create instances of each one. Alternatively I could [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) each class if it hasn't been declared already, then use a combination of [`get_declared_classes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) and [`get_class_methods`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php)... But both of these seem like bad ideas as they would consume a lot of memory. Is there a more efficient way?

**EDIT:** My attempt using [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all)

```
function getDirectoryList($dir) {
    $dirList = $fileList = [];
    $iter = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

    foreach ($iter as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()) {
            $dirList[$file->getFilename()] = getDirectoryList($file->getPathname());
        } else {
            $fileList[$file->getFilename()] = $file->getFilename();
        }
    }

    uksort($dirList, 'strnatcmp');
    natsort($fileList);
    return $dirList + $fileList;
}

$path = '/var/www/html/dev/lib/framework/controllers';
$classes = getDirectoryList($path);
foreach ($classes as $class) {
    $file = $path . '/' . $class;
    echo $file . '<br />';
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
    $method = $namespace = $buffer = '';
    $i = 0;
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $buffer .= fread($fp, 512);
        $tokens = token_get_all($buffer);

        if (strpos($buffer, '{') === false) {
            continue;
        }

        for (; $i<count($tokens); $i++) {
            if ($tokens[$i][0] === T_NAMESPACE) {
                for ($j=$i+1;$j<count($tokens); $j++) {
                    if ($tokens[$j][0] === T_STRING) {
                         $namespace .= '\\'.$tokens[$j][1];
                    } else if ($tokens[$j] === '{' || $tokens[$j] === ';') {
                         break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($tokens[$i][0] === T_FUNCTION) {
                for ($j=$i+1;$j<count($tokens);$j++) {
                    if ($tokens[$j] === '{') {
                        $method = $tokens[$i+2][1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($method);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

This gives me output as follows:

```
/var/www/html/dev/lib/framework/controllers/AuthController.php
string(8) "register"
string(14) "registerSubmit"
string(14) "registerSubmit"
string(14) "registerSubmit"
string(14) "registerSubmit"
string(14) "registerSubmit"
string(14) "registerSubmit"
string(14) "registerSubmit"
string(14) "registerSubmit"
string(5) "login"
string(5) "login"
string(5) "login"
string(5) "login"
string(5) "login"
string(5) "login"
string(6) "logout"
string(6) "verify"
string(6) "verify"
string(6) "verify"
string(6) "verify"
string(12) "verifySubmit"
string(12) "verifySubmit"
string(12) "verifySubmit"
string(12) "verifySubmit"
string(12) "verifySubmit"
string(12) "verifySubmit"
string(12) "verifySubmit"
```

Several of the methods are repeated. Also, it doesn't seem to catch *all* of the methods, for example `loginSubmit` should be listed. Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3yCCa3RU) of the whole class as a reference. And I'm still not sure if this is even the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: So why not `token_get_all`?

Comment: @zerkms I'm not sure how, considering there is no [parser token](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) "method" equivalent of `T_CLASS`

Comment: `T_FUNCTION` inside `T_CLASS` (only the first level of depth though) is a method.

Comment: @zerkms I've tried with `T_FUNCTION` using the examples in the links provided to no avail. Even though they're only searching for a single class name, not multiple method names, I can't seem to get anything useful out of it. I can update my question with the failed attempts if you like.

Comment: If you post your attempt - it increases chances to get an answer. See "help me with this code" vs "write everything for me"

Comment: @zerkms updated with code example and (un)expected results.

Comment: "for example loginSubmit should be listed" --- without having sources of the original file it's not obvious for us.

Comment: @zerkms added pastebin.

Comment: If you can figure out what the classes are (*if you have conventional naming*), why not use [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) on said class name in your loop to generate method names as required. (***Note:*** this fetches the defined methods within the class, not the ones called.)

Comment: @Darren because that would require every class to be declared first... As stated in the question.

Comment: Whoops, read straight past that!

Comment: i tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4068490/1225672 and its working