# php implemented interface cannot be found

Tags: php, interface

When i implemented an interface in a class and executed the code, it appeared the following error:

---

```
Fatal error: Interface 'IConn' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\aulaPHP\SoNet\php_oo\OO_advanced\code_03_class_conn\Conn.php on line 3
```

---

The problem in this is that all the files are correctly placed, together, but the Interface cannot be found at the "Conn" file.
Here's the code:

---

```
<?php 

class Conn implements IConn
{
    private $dsn;
    private $user;
    private $pass;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $pass)
    {
        $this->dsn = $dsn;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        return new \PDO($this->dsn,$this->user,$this->pass);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: do you use an autoloader ? If not, you're just missing a `require` statement here to the interface file

Comment: I wasn't missing a require, but the require was after the class that it was being used by, making it "invisible". You helped anyway, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely missing a`require` statement for the interface, if you are not using an autoloader.

Have a look at this [answere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669266/php-how-to-autoload-interfaces-and-abstracts) about autoloading interfaces and abstract classes . I would also recommend you to consider [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading), since it is one of the most common php dependency management tools, well documented and easy to use.

Comment: I wasn't missing a `require`, but the require was after the class that it was being used by, making it "invisible". You helped anyway, thx!