# List PHP functions (builtin and optional) that are used by a site

Tags: php

UPDATE: resolved with a PHP parser. Let's reopen so that I can answer and accept.

---

I'm considering moving a PHP site to a new host. I've got a shared plan on both source and target hosts, therefore limited access to PHP customization.

Certain PHP function families (openssl, mcrypt, gd to name a few) may not be available on the new host. In order to match the API surface against the host, I'd like to statically list all PHP functions, both standalone and class methods, that my files reference.

There's very little dynamic code, so API references that are hidden behind `eval` are not a concern. Static analysis would be sufficient.

I've tried phpCallGraph with -p and Doxygen - both produce incomplete coverage. Are there any other tools to that effect out there, please?

EDIT: the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908228/list-all-classes-and-methods-in-a-script-file) is utterly inapplicable. It's *called* functions I'm after, not *defined* ones.

EDIT2: I would like to avoid retesting *the whole site*. Just the portions that depend on module provided functions.

Comment: exactly how do you "look" for an api on a server? it's http... you can try firing off an infinite number of key=value pairs as query strings and post bodies, but you're not likely to have much luck getting anything other than 4xx/5xx codes.

Comment: I was going to specifically spot-test code paths that depend on obscure APIs. It's my site, I know the logic pretty well. I also know that testing for 100% coverage is not something I wanna do :)

Comment: By "API references", do you just mean "built-in functions"? And by "function families", you mean "extensions", right?

Comment: Are you looking in particular to list called functions from PHP modules in particular? Usually applications should have a well-defined set of required modules, and they should bomb out if they are not loaded. These are usually noted in set-up files and the like, so you can go to a host and ask them what modules they support.

Comment: @IMSoP: Right. Bad choice of words. Fixed.

Comment: @halfer: There should be, but there isn't :) The codebase evolved over quite some time.

Comment: Xdebug & a fun afternoon with WinCacheGrind? :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881588/php-get-called-functions-list

Comment: Um, that's dynamic analysis. I'm after static.

Comment: This seems like a good fit for the new [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Solved with [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) and an hour of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) and an hour of work.

Go through all PHP files in a folder, parse each one. Go through the parse tree, identify function calls, store the function names. Identify function definition statements, store the names of these. At the end, subtract the latter from the former, dump the result. Same for class method invokations.