# Getting all model classes in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, model

I am using Laravel 4.2 for a project. I need to get all model classes. I have tried 'get_declared_classes' but it doesn't have worked. I am researching other ways now and need your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22761554/1903366) could help