# Automatically instantiate classes based on certain interfaces

Tags: php, oop, interface

I am sorry if this question was asked and answered elsewhere --- I do not know how to phrase my question in a proper way. Any hint will help.

I have "a bunch" of PHP-classes organised by PSR-4 principles (folders = class names, subfolder = sub-namespace-paths). There are sub-namespaces like accounting, printing, production, etc. Each of these subnamespaces might have an unknown amount of classes.

There is an interface in `mynamespace\core\interfaces\types`. And there are classes that implement this interface in for example `mynamespace\core\something.php` and `mynamespace\core\subnamespace\somethingelse.php` and `mynamespace\accounting\othertypes.php`, etc... and so on...

**Is there a "proper" way to "know" all classes in this `mynamespace` implementing `mynamespace\core\interfaces\types` and running automatically a sub-method of these classes?**

The specific user case here might be a group of "options" that are encapsulated in classes or "menu-items" in classes that can be "collected" and then initialise themselves somehow.

Update: Is there a way to use `Reflection`-classes on a namespace to evaluate this information maybe?

Comment: Sounds like something you could do with annotations and a DIC compiler pass, which would be better than scraping your classes.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably looking for this [haydenpierce/class-finder](https://packagist.org/packages/haydenpierce/class-finder)

check if this answer will be helpful for you because from what I understood the thread both problems look identical and only differ in the implementation
[How to get all class names inside a particular namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40229665/11489441)

Comment: I actually landed yesterday on [NastuzziSamy/reflection-namespace](https://github.com/NastuzziSamy/reflection-namespace), which does the same as haydenpierce/class-finder. I will be testing both of them.