# Get name of last declared class

Tags: php, class

I want to dynamically declare classes (= require .php files), but I need to know, which class was actually defined (all I need is name). My current solution is:

```
$classesBefore = get_declared_classes();
require_once $someToken'.php'; // it's actualy more complex than this...
$classesAfter = get_declared_classes();

$classesDiff = array_diff($classesAfter, $classesBefore);
$declaredClass = end($classesDiff);

echo $declaredClass; // here is name of currently declared class
```

Can this be done more efficient way? And if not, can I be sure that last defined class will be last at defined classes list (because of `$declaredClass = end($classesDiff);`)?

Comment: So what do you do after you learn this class `example` was the last declared class? Does the order even matter

Answer (score 0):

There is another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928928/determining-what-classes-are-defined-in-a-php-class-file) with alternate solutions to do what you're looking for. Here's the snippet from that post:

```
function file_get_php_classes($filepath) {
  $php_code = file_get_contents($filepath);
  $classes = get_php_classes($php_code);
  return $classes;
}

function get_php_classes($php_code) {
  $classes = array();
  $tokens = token_get_all($php_code);
  $count = count($tokens);
  for ($i = 2; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if (   $tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS
        && $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE
        && $tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING) {

        $class_name = $tokens[$i][1];
        $classes[] = $class_name;
    }
  }
  return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Instead of marking it as a possible duplicate or write a comment you just going to copy the entire code from the other post? This doesn't serve anybody!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done more easy:

```
require_once $someToken'.php';
$last_class = array_pop(get_declared_classes());
```

> *edit:
>   As written in the comments on this post, this can bring up a notice.
>   This can be prevented by using one more line:

```
$all_classes = get_declared_classes();
$last_class = array_pop($all_classes);
```

thank for the hint.

Of course you can also use end() instead of array_pop(). This should result in the same.

As an alternative you could use this snippet to get the last declared class:

```
require_once $someToken'.php';
$all_classes = get_declared_classes();
$all_classes_rev = array_reverse($all_classes);
$last_class = $all_classes_rev[0];
```

which is some kind less elegant.

Back to the first approach:
array_pop(get_declared_classes()) brings you the last declared class always

of course this does not include the case you define multiple classes before calling array_pop(get_declared_classes())
so the above line must be used every time you include a new class what makes it not being "D.R.Y". You should perhaps therefore consider another way of solving that problem.

This is a complete different way which would be more elegant:

Create a Helper class that you can use to register new classes:

```
/* the helper: */
class MyDefinedClasses {
  $classes = array();

  public static function register_class($class){
    self::$classes[] = $class
  }

  public static function get_registered_classes(){
    return self::$classes;
  }
}
/*helper ends here*/
```

here one class as example of these you include and write your self:

```
/*misc function class to be registered*/
class MyFunctions {
  public ....
}
myDefinedClasses::register_class(new MyFunctions()); // this is where the alternative approach of solving your problem kicks in
/*(php)file ends here*/
```

now you are always able to get all your custom and registered classes by calling myDefinedClasses::get_registered_classes();

and the best about it: you directly got a class instance without using php's reflection functionality

Comment: Did you tested your answer? (`Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`)

Comment: then you just need to do one more line... `$foo = get_declared_classes();
$last_class = array_pop($foo);`

Comment: And then: Welcome back again with 2 lines, now OP also can just use `end()` and doesn't have to change anything

Comment: `end(get_declared_classes())` does also bring up `PHP Strict Standards` warning